# Auto increment will not autofill link number

Tags: excel

I am trying to do auto fill on links like this

```
https://foo.com/1.jpg
https://foo.com/2.jpg

....

https://foo.com/316.jpg
```

Everytime I try to auto fill, it just repeats what i added.

can any one help?

Comment: use a formula: `="https://foo.com/" & row(A1) & ".jpg"`.

Comment: So easy!  yet searched for hours on this..  thanks